# Ctrl + F not finding input values?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

So within every other modern browser, ctrl+F can find values of input fields. In IE(X), however, it doesn't find it at all. Is there a way to get the find functionality to find those values? Or is there an attribute/tag/property that can be used to get that functionality?

It needs to find values in input tags.

Comment: You could try to override that functionality and implement it yourself, seems like too much work for very little benefit though.

Comment: I'd assume that it's just not a functionality within IE then. Which is rather annoying honestly.

Comment: Why are you relying on browsers to support this? What usage are you getting out of it?

Comment: There are users that have requested to be able to search a lot of records using ctrl+f in IE, is the main reason.

It might just be better left as a low-priority function, if that.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply to some of this.  
@MrPablo, the reason for the browser reliance is that in a large company, too often there's developers that implement their own search tool into an application.  And... it's crap.

Comment: In addition, a custom search tool built into an application becomes another training point.  The extra training point, I know, many will scoff at.  But I watch application after application go through the door with "obvious" and "well made" features, that never get used because people don't get it.  Ctrl + F is a common cross browser feature.  Those features are golden.  Teach a user to use your custom search function.  Doesn't work anywhere else in life for that user.  Teach a user Ctrl+F and let them know it works on their favorite aquarium site, they never forget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IE developer tools, it has its own "Search for items" where you can find specific text inside the markup

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the users need to be able to do this, not just me. I know about that already. And I can't just tell the end users to F12 for it either.

Comment: agreed.  Developer Tools isn't an option for standard users.  I'm having the same trouble right now.  If anyone found a solution outside of putting a label with the value on the page, I'd love to know.