# ASP.Net TextBox and CTRL+F not working

Tags: html, forms, browser, cross-browser

I'm simply looking for a solution to make a web browsers CTRL+F work with TextBoxes in ASP.Net.  This is a web form, though any TextBox I create, renders as an  and for some reason, the Text displayed on page can't be searched via a browsers CTRL+F page search feature.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbxTest" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="GridViewTextBoxCenteringNoBorder"  Text='<%# Bind("TestDBColumn") %>' Tooltip='<%# Bind("TestDBColumn") %>' onchange="javascript: RowTextChanged( this )" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried just now, and I could find the text in a TextBox with Firefox, but not with IE-11. Are you using IE? This might be a browser specific issue.

Comment: yeah using IE.  hm.  well that's going to be annoying... it's a standard here.

Comment: found the same question here, no answer really for this one either.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308265/ctrl-f-not-finding-input-values